# Continuous functions on the unit simplex

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, convex-analysis

For some $n\in\mathbb N$, define the unit simplex as $$S\equiv\left\{\mathbf x\in\mathbb R_+^n\,\middle|\,\sum_{i=1}^nx_i=1\right\}.$$ For each $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, suppose that $f^i:S\to\mathbb R_+$ is a non-negative continuous function, $\alpha^i\geq0$ is a number, and let $\mathbf e^i\in S$ denote the vector whose $i$th coordinate is $1$ and all other coordinates are $0$. Suppose that the functions are such that

- $f^i(\mathbf e^i)\geq\alpha^i$ for every $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$; and
- $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^nf^i(\mathbf x)\geq\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha^i$ for every $\mathbf x\in S$.

> **Question:** Does there necessarily exist some $\mathbf x^*\in S$ such that $f^i(\mathbf x^*)\geq\alpha^i$ for every $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$?

The answer is affirmative for $n=2$ and it easily follows from the intermediate-value theorem. For higher dimensions, I am stuck with coming up with a proof—in fact, I feel diffidence as to whether the answer is affirmative in the first place.

Any hints or counterexamples would be appreciated.

Comment: I have finaly erased my answer. I had attempted an approach using barycentrical coordinates without success... Can you say a little about the motivation for this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a counter example in $n=3$.

Let $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\alpha_3=1,$ $f(e_1)=(1,1.5,0.5),$ $f(e_2)=(0.5,1,1.5),$ $f(e_3)=(1.5,0.5,1).$ Let $x_0=(1,1,-1)$ (on the same plane with $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$). Let $f(x_0)=(1,1,1)$. ($x_0$ is the wanted $x^*$, but not in the simplex.)

Linearly extend $f$ on $\overline{e_1e_3},$ $\overline{e_2e_3},$ then linearly extend $f$ on $\{\overline{e_1e_3},x_0\},$ $\{\overline{e_2e_3},x_0\},$ the counter example is done, on the triangle $e_1e_2e_3$. Linearly extend it to $S$ is easy.

So when $n\ge 3,$ we cannot expect $x^*$ exsit in $S.$

Comment: The motivation is: 

1. We only need to consider plane $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$;

2. Linearly extend $f$ directly will cause $x^*=\frac{e_1+e_2+e_3}{3}$ to be the only point satisfys the condition.

3. We can lift $x^*$ up into $3$-dimension, shift it, then project it outside the triangle $e_1e_2e_3,$ without causing conflict.

4. When there's only $e_1e_2,$ conflict will always happen on the end.

Comment: This doesn’t work. The unique linear functions satisfying the boundary conditions you stated at $\mathbf e^1$, $\mathbf e^2$, and $\mathbf e^3$ are
\begin{align*}
f^1(\mathbf x)&=\phantom{\frac{1}{2}}x_1+\frac{1}{2}x_2+\frac{3}{2}x_3,\\f^2(\mathbf x)&=\frac{3}{2}x_1+\phantom{\frac{1}{2}}x_2+\frac{1}{2}x_3,\\f^3(\mathbf x)&=\frac{1}{2}x_1+\frac{3}{2}x_2+\phantom{\frac{1}{2}}x_3.
\end{align*}
But then $f^i(1/3,1/3,1/3)=1=\alpha^i$ for each $i\in\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: @triple_sec $f$ is not a linear function. It's linear in the triangle $e_1e_3x_0$, $e_2e_3x_0.$ You can see my comment about the motivation.